# How to compare the number of odd values to the number of even numbers in a column?

Tags: matlab, matrix

How to determine if there are more odd values than even values in a column of a matrix?

For example, if the column consists of `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]`, then the number of odd values is larger than the number of even values.

Comment: `oddsWin = sum(mod(X, 2), 1) > size(X, 1)/2`

Comment: I prefer `mode(mod(x))`. It’s golfier.

Comment: Sorry, `mode(mod(x,2))`.

Comment: @beaker You should post this as a code golf challenge :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I’m sure there's a 1-byte solution somewhere. ;)

Comment: ozoz, if you're still looking for a solution, please post a [mre] showing what you've tried and where your attempts went wrong or what you'd like to change.

Comment: thanks for your answer it is what i am looking for @beaker